# calculate the mad() of every two values of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
 index                                   data
11727.213152                           -62.260842
12144.825397                           -26.384420
12566.138322                           -47.091084
12981.362812                           -74.528391
```

I would like to calculate the mad() value of every two items of the data column, how can i do that?
Is there a way to group the data column in groups of two (or more)?
Or should I simply iterate through the df and calculate the mad of two consequent values?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by helper array created by flooring division by `//`:

```
s = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 2)['data'].mad()
print (s)
0    17.938211
1    13.718653
Name: data, dtype: float64
```

**Detail**:

```
print (np.arange(len(df)) // 2)
[0 0 1 1]
```

Comment: great, thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was looking for!